# How do Russians surely increase chances to get tourist Visas to America?

Tags: visas, usa, visa-refusals, russian-citizens

Russians say that it's hard trying to vacation to America. Is it true one's chances of entry via tourist visa is poorly affected by the following:

- is a young single woman
- who has recently finished school
- who has an empty passport (hasn't been to other countries)
- who doesn't have other countries on their passport

This, in parts, seems sexist. I want to know all that lowers the chances for Russians seeking a tourist visa.

Comment: Since it's hard to go to America Russians just choose different destinations when considering vacation. This is especially true since current consulate situation makes it infeasible to apply for visa unless you really have to.

Answer (score 3):

Under US law, the nonimmigrant visa applicant has to overcome the presumption of immigrant intent, that is, that person must demonstrate that they have good reasons to return to their country after their visit.

How to do this varies by individual circumstances. Being a current student, having a good job, or family in one's home country will help. Being unemployed or a former student will not help.

Travel history isn't really all that helpful, but it could be a point in your favor. Thousands of people with no travel history get US visas every day. But if you have traveled to various places in the West such as the UK or Schengen, it would make your application look a small bit better.

As for gender, a young woman out of school with no income or travel history would be considered about the same as a young man out of school with no income or travel history. Neither is likely to be approved for a visa.

Finally, do not send money to anyone who claims to be a woman in Russia who says they need money to pay for various expenses relating to obtaining a US visa or traveling to the US, and that you do not already personally know. These are virtually always [scams](https://ru.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/victims-of-crime/dating-scams/).

Comment: The points listed in the question to me seem more like [signs of a honey trap](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/europe/russian-honeytrap-secrets-lies-sex-and-spies-1742543.html), not of an illegal immigrant.

Comment: @JJJ It's not about illegal immigration, but Internet dating scams.

Comment: That seems like a bit of a stretch. Nothing in the question suggests this to be in relation to an internet scam. In particular, you bring up sending money to someone you don't know, it's not in the question.

Comment: @JJJ We see this sort of thing here once or twice a week. This user - who is American - is asking some of the same sorts of questions that others have asked after someone tried to scam them in this way. It's certainly possible that nobody is trying to scam him, but I wouldn't take that bet if I were you.

Comment: Fair enough. I read the question differently: American user hears somewhere that their country may have an immigration policy they deem sexist. They ask if this policy is real or if it's just some story. As for your advice sending money to strangers, that seems pretty obvious and if you really want to say it I think it should be a comment rather than an answer. The first two paragraph try to answer the question but could be more explicit (e.g. reference the bullet points in the question).

Comment: @JJJ You're right, there were points that I forgot to address. I have edited the answer. I think it is more complete now.